# OpenMP, random variables, and reproducibility

Tags: r, openmp, reproducible-research

I'm writing an R code, which calls C++, and C++ functions use a lot of parallel computing based on openMP. This is my first code using openMP and what I saw is that even setting the same C++ random seed, the code never gives the same results.
I read a lot of posts here, where it seems that this is an issue with openMP, but they are all old (between12 to 5 years ago)
I want to know if there are solutions now and if there are published article which explain this problem or/and possible solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on parallel random number generation. This is not an OpenMP problem, but one that will afflict any use of random numbers in a parallel code.
Start with
[Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3 - The Salmons](http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf)